# Can't navigate to app window on different desktop from App Exposé

Tags: mission-control, expose

From macOS [App Exposé](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission_Control_(macOS)#:%7E:text=Also%20called%20%27App%20Expos%C3%A9%27.,by%20pressing%20the%20tab%20key.), I should be able to click on an app window, then automatically switch to the desktop with that app window. But on my macOS Sonoma 14.1.1 machine, when I can launch App Exposé and see all the windows; but when I click on a different window, nothing happens—I stay on my current desktop instead of navigating to the app window on a different desktop.

Is there some Mission Control or App Exposé setting that I'm missing? I tried to take a cursory look through the *Mission Control* menu in the System Settings app (but I didn't find anything obviously wrong—see screenshot), restarting the Dock process with the `killall Dock` command, and restarting my laptop; but to no avail!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it! I had a *`workspaces-auto-swoosh`* setting toggled off. I discovered that setting by looking through the *`defaults read`* command like the following shell session illustrates:

```
$ defaults read
# ...
    "com.apple.dock" =     {
# ...
        "workspaces-auto-swoosh" = 0;
# ...
    };
# ...
```

**Observation:** Notice that *`workspaces-auto-swoosh`* setting is toggled off—unexpected. **Guess:** The *automatically switch to the desktop* behavior I was talking about earlier is called *auto swoosh* and I had inadvertently toggled that behavior off. **Note:** I couldn't find that setting in the System Settings app when I search for "swoosh".

To resolve, delete that setting and restart Dock process with the following commands:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dock workspaces-auto-swoosh
killall Dock
```